# What is the fastest way to check if files in a folder exist in my mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, scandir

I want to scan a folder of effects and check if each file is listed as a row in my MySQL database of effects, and if it isn't I will show it as an un-tracked file. Does anyone know an efficient method to achieve this with PHP? thank you very much.

Comment: What is the scale for amount of entries. Hundred, few thousand, millions ?

Comment: Hi, right now it is only around 300 but probably will be up to 1500 files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's only one way: [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) the directory, prepare two statements (a check and an update) using PDO or mysqli and loop through the files.

If you need to do it on a regular basis, you should move the tracked files to a different place as soon as you track / check them.

Answer (score 0):

The best way, that i can think of, would be to store `registration_date` along with the `filename` in the table.

- select latest updated/added file from DB, get the timestamp for that file
- create a prepared statement for adding a filename to the table
- loop through the the list of file in your directory looking for file which are [newer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getmtime.php) then the timestamp
- insert each filename, which fits the conditions, and current timestamp into the table
- if there is violation of `UNIQUE` constraint, it means that file has been updated, not added.

IMHO, this would be the most effective way to do this.